# Zip file not downloading using Ajax in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to download a  zip file containing .pdf files by ajax call. Here is my code. Only the zip file is not downloading, the rest are ok.

```
public FileResult DownloadZip(string[] Paths) {
    string FilePath = string.Empty;
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()) {
        foreach (var item in Paths) {
            string updateitem = item.Replace("'", "");
            FilePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportPath"] + updateitem;

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath)) {
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath)) { continue; }
                if (!zip.ContainsEntry(FilePath)) { zip.AddFile(FilePath); }
            }
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",attachmentfilename=DocumentFiles.zip");
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

        var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        memStream.Position = 0;

        return File(memStream, "application/zip", "DocumentFiles.zip");
    }
}

$("#btnDownload").click(function () {
    var reportPaths = new Array();
    $('input[name="path"]:checked').each(function() {
        reportPaths.push(this.value);
    });
    $.ajax({type: "GET",url: "/Client/CompletedCases/DownloadZip",traditional: true,data:{Paths:reportPaths},success: function (data) {},});
});
```

Comment: `Here is my code.` <-- There @ImabAsghar

Comment: what a code... i like this code....may i borrow :D :D

Comment: I was editing the code.

Comment: onsuccess of ajax you did nothing..you have to write code accroding to response of your ajax request

Comment: but i am returning a file in c# code.

Comment: ya but you have to specify what to do with that responsed...like open or save or etc and that will be in that section..your code is not completed so how it can work

Comment: Can you please suggest me ?

Comment: Does your code really have to be in one line per statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Download(string file)
{   
  string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles"), file);
  return File(fullPath, "application/zip", file);
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Download', //change it accroding to your url
    data: '{ "file" : "file" }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (returnValue) {
        window.location = '/Download?file=' + returnValue; //change accroding to you url
    }
});
```